# Azure cli Azure Devops error: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-cli

Here are the commands I am executing in Azure CLI:

```
C:\Users\dell>az devops login
Token: (token entered)
```

Here is the response:

> TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource.

I logged out and logged in multiple times and regenerated tokens, still same issue.

From the browser interface, it's working.

Comment: have you tried with --org with the organization name? `az devops login --org ORGANIZATION_NAME`

Comment: Did you are trying to login to TFS? I notice that you add the tag `TFS`. Did you login with the account successfully after execute the command `az login`?

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue and it is fixed by below code

```
$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = '$(System.AccessToken)'
az pipelines build tag add --build-id $(Build.BuildId) --tags CodeDeploy --detect true
```

az login is not required if you directly set the environment variable AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT with System.AccessToken or your PAT

run any command without having to sign in explicitly. Each command will try to use the PAT in the environment variable for authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps you can follow:

```
az login
```

This will list out all the subscription you profile is attached with, then you can call

```
az devops login
Token:
```

I tried this and was able to successfully log in without any error.

You can then set your default organization and project by using below command:

```
 az devops configure --defaults organization=https://sample.visualstudio.com project=sample-project
```

and then you can use any of the available commands with `az devops` like below:

```
az pipelines build list -o table
```

i was able to successfully get the list of available build in the above mentioned set project.

[image]

P.S.: Please note that , you can directly use `az devops login` too for logging in to devops server, i have added alternative  `az login` just to resolve login issue.

Hope it helps.